# "Falta SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column" al insertar datos de una tabla en otra tabla

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, fedora

Tengo un archivo de datos de un etl que crea una consulta SQL para insertar una fecha, un userID y un idioma en una tabla de base de datos MySQL 5.7 desde una otra tabla.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO {db_name}.unique_open_emails
                (date, user_id, lang)
            SELECT DATE(timestamp), user_id, lang
            FROM sendgridevents
            WHERE timestamp >= '{two_days_ago}'
                AND event = 'open'
                AND NOT user_id IS NULL
            GROUP BY DATE(timestamp), user_id;
```

Pero obtengo:

```
2021-07-07 10:04:45.396505 - Complete table unique_open_emails
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/ac/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools/etl/main.py", line 51, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/ac/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools/etl/main.py", line 30, in main
    unique_users.main()  # depends on users
  File "/home/ac/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools/etl/task/unique_users.py", line 110, in main
    complete_table_unique_open_emails()
  File "/home/ac/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools/etl/task/unique_users.py", line 11, in complete_table_unique_open_emails
    c.execute("""
  File "/home/ac/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 206, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/home/ac/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 319, in _query
    db.query(q)
  File "/home/ac/Documents/Programming/Work/data-tools/venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 259, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1055, "Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'archive.sendgridevents.lang' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by")
```

El objetivo es para migrar de la biblioteca mysqlclient 1.3.7 a la 2.0.3. Aqui esta el codigo.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from etl.utils.logging import info
from etl.mysql.connect import db, db_name, db_archive
from etl.mysql.operations import add_column_if_not_exists, add_index_if_not_exists


def complete_table_unique_open_emails():
    two_days_ago = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=2)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    with db_archive as c:
        c.execute("""
            INSERT IGNORE INTO {db_name}.unique_open_emails
                (date, user_id, lang)
            SELECT DATE(timestamp), user_id, lang
            FROM sendgridevents
            WHERE timestamp >= '{two_days_ago}'
                AND event = 'open'
                AND NOT user_id IS NULL
            GROUP BY DATE(timestamp), user_id;"""
                  .format(db_name=db_name, two_days_ago=two_days_ago))
```

Comment: Prueba sin GROUP BY.

Comment: Tienes que agregar `lang` al `GROUP BY` eso es lo que te indica el error.

Comment: lang falta en group by ... traduccion del error